# Not able to grant a role to the group in beeline

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2, beeline

I am trying to grant a role to the AD group in beeline. I am facing the below error. If anyone has encountered the same issue, Please suggest me the steps to resolve.

> GRANT ROLE role_test1 TO GROUP test1;
>   Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Invalid principal type in principal Principal [name=itops_hdp3_saie_archive_rw, type=GROUP] (state=08S01,code=1)

Comment: Is there any justification for that `mysql` tag?

Comment: Version of Hive? Distro? Are Sentry or Ranger used to manage authorizations? Kerberized cluster or not? How did you map the AD users/groups to Hadoop users/groups -- via Linux users/groups *(using `sssd` for example)*?

Comment: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1.2.3.2.0-2950) , Hortonworks 2.3.2 . Cluster is not kerberized and we didn't install Sentry or Ranger to manage authorizations. Created AD groups and adding users with their NT accounts to that groups. then creating roles in hive and trying to grant the  access to the AD group.

Comment: Again: how do you make these AD groups visible to Hive? Did you set up **HiveServer2** to use **LDAP authentication** against your AD servers? Or did you configure globally the **Linux hosts** to use **AD authentication**?

Comment: Yes, HiveServer2 is set up to use LDAP authentication to the AD servers.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070419/hive-authorization-dont-have-support-for-group

Answer (score 0):

One of the many, many, many critical informations that you did not give was: **what [Authorization Model](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Authorization) do you use?**

- with Ranger enabled *(...not the case here...)*
- with Sentry enabled *(...not the case here...)*
- with [SQL Standard Based Hive Authorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization) you can GRANT privileges to a User or a Role, you can GRANT membership of a Role to a User -- but **there is currently no concept of Group** *(see sources below)*; and it works only with HiveServer2, the Hive CLI does not enforce these privileges restrictions anyway
- with the [Legacy Mode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Default+Authorization+-+Legacy+Mode) you could indeed GRANT privileges to a Group...

Some interesting sources:
  > [mail thread](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2016-05/msg16252.html) - Q: *"Hive SQL based authorization don't have support for group?"* -- A: *"we haven’t added that feature"* (2016-05-26)
  > [Hive unit tests](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/test/queries/clientnegative/authorization_grant_group.q) - comment: *"grant insert on group should fail"* (was in SVN trunk as of 2016-09-21)